# Using a variable value in json_table

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I have the following json:

```
{
    "title": "title",
    "description": "description",
    "references": [{
        "reference_id": 181
    },
{
        "reference_id": 182
    }]
}
```

I want to insert the data of references array in a table xyz which contains the following columns:
buffer_id  and reference_id

```
INSERT INTO xyz (
        buffer_id,
        reference_id
    )
        SELECT
            l_buffer_id,
            reference_id
        FROM
            dual,
            JSON_TABLE ( data, '$.references[*]'
                    COLUMNS (
                        l_buffer_id ,
                        reference_id NUMBER PATH '$.reference_id'
                    )
                );
```

Here, l_buffer_id is a variable where my value is stored. I tried the above method to insert data into xyz. However it is not working. Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such a mechanism :

```
INSERT INTO xyz (
        buffer_id,
        reference_id
    )
WITH tab(data) AS
(
 SELECT '{"title": "title",
    "description": "description",
    "references": [{
        "reference_id": 181
    },
{
        "reference_id": 182
    }]
}' FROM dual
)
SELECT row_number() over (order by reference_id) as l_buffer_id,
       reference_id
  FROM tab,
       json_table(data, '$'
               COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$."references"[*]'
                   COLUMNS (reference_id NUMBER PATH '$."reference_id"')));
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cff0be39ad4f5826f318ca4717c9b5c2)</kbd>